# Yii2 - how to route for the page

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I am a new in the learning Yii2 framework (installed advanced version of Yii2). 
Currently I am having "standart" front-end with top-menu (Home / About / Contact etc.). I would like to add in the top-menu additional section (e.g. "Advanced Contact" that is displaying advanced Contact Form.

So, I have done the next:

Added in the main.php additional menu section

```
$menuItems = [
                ['label' => 'Home', 'url' => ['/site/index']],
                ['label' => 'About', 'url' => ['/site/about']],
                ['label' => 'Contact', 'url' => ['/site/contact']],
                ['label' => 'Advanced Contact', 'url' => ['/site/advancedcontact']]
            ];
```

Copied the ContactPage view (contact.php) as advancedcontact.php in the same folder.

But after pressing the link I am getting the message

Not Found (#404)
Unable to resolve the request: site/advancedcontact

What should I follow to correct this error?

Comment: Add controller code.

Comment: Copy and Paste is a bad thing,, unless you have stated you started learning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you also copy the function in the controller? in frontend/controllers/SiteController.php you should have something like this.

```
/**
     * Advanced Contact Form action
     *
     * Renders the advanced contact page and processes any form submissions.
     *
     * @return string Rendering result
     */
    public function actionAdvancedcontact()
    {
        $model = new ContactForm();
        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->validate()) {
            if ($model->sendEmail(Yii::$app->params['adminEmail'])) {
                Yii::$app->session->setFlash('success', 'Thank you for contacting us. We will respond to you as soon as possible.');
            } else {
                Yii::$app->session->setFlash('error', 'There was an error sending email.');
            }
            return $this->refresh();
        } else {
            return $this->render('advancedcontact', [
                'model' => $model,
            ]);
        }
    }
```

Note that if you rename the function to actionAdvancedContact then your route needs to be /site/advanced-contact

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Yes, I have added actionAdvancedcontact(). Problem was in the  "advanced-contact" (not "advancedcontact" )